# ¿Cuál es el formato correcto para el método post en Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular5

Al leer la documentación veo que el método post en angular 5 se debería llamar así

```
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

Sin embargo, en la documentación no enseña cuál es el formato de la variable `hero` ni la de `httpOptions`, ni tampoco explican cómo llamar los datos de un formulario en la sección html del módulo. La pregunta es ¿cómo hago esto?

Answer (score 1):

En el [ejemplo Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1) de Angular5 sí que explica lo que comentas. Por un lado indican que `Hero` es una clase con este aspecto:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Y [httpOptions](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) es una constante donde se definen las cabeceras del `POST`:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
```

Respecto a lo último, ¿a qué te refieres exactamente? ¿A cómo acceder en tu html a las variables de tu `component`? Si es eso, una forma es la interpolación. En el ejemplo también lo indican:

**heroes.component.ts (hero property)**

```
hero = 'Windstorm';
```

**heroes.component.html**

```
{{hero}}
```

Comment: como obtengo los datos del formulario en el componente html y lo asigno en hero?
mejor dicho, cuando se crea un componente por ejemplo con el método 
ng g c hero
crea tres archivos, el hero.component.ts, hero.html y hero.css; y pues lo que quiero saber es, suponiendo que creo un formulario en el componente html asignarle una variable dentro del hero.component.ts

Comment: En este caso lo hace con un Two-way databinding con ngModel: <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"> También está explicado en el ejemplo